# How to check if a div contains a certain word and check if that certain word matchs a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So I am using Node.JS and doing a small multiplayer project.

Of course I'm using JavaScript for a lot of things.
I would like to check if a `div` contains a certain word and if that certain word matches a variable.

How would I do this with JavaScript?

I want something like:

```
var teststring = "hi";
if "<div id="test">" contents matches "teststring"
{

}
```

I also have jQuery so that's an option too!
I'm new to JavaScript so please fire away!

This was my attempt but it didn't work:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://*');
socket.on('field', function (data) {
    if ($("#userid").text().indexOf(data) > -1)
    {   
        window.alert('lol');    
        console.log(data);
        $("#field").html(data);
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert("Something has gone wrong with the node server...");
    }
});
```

Comment: `if( document.getElementById('test').textContent.indexOf(teststring) > -1)` should do it...

Comment: And is this in the browser, or in Node? I'm guessing it's on the clientside, just not sure why you're mentioning Node ?

Comment: `if ($("#test:contains('" + teststring + "')").length) {}`

Answer (score 4):

Just check the contents of the div with the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function of jQuery, like this:

```
var teststring = "hi";
if ($("#test").text().indexOf(teststring) > -1)
{
    alert("Match!");
}
```

Comment: Basically the same as my comment, but with slightly more browser compatibility (`innerText` used internally) and a thousand more instructions to process XD +1

Comment: @user3818791 What exactly didn't work? Provide a fiddle please.

Comment: @user3818791 What does `data` contain in your response?

Comment: data(message) coming from node

Comment: You have a line `console.log(data);` in your code. What does it say in the console?

Answer (score 1):

to get the value of the div you can use

```
var divValue = $('#test').text();

var teststring = "hi";
```

and to match with the variable;

```
   if(divValue === teststring ){

      alert('Two variables are matching !!');

   }
```

and to search a String contains a substring you can use;

```
 if (divValue.indexOf(teststring ) >= 0)
  {
    alert('Two variables are matching !!');
   }
```

please visit http://jsfiddle.net/dennypanther/ojmyobL8/

Comment: "CONTAINS a certain word"

Comment: That's comparing the entire content of the div, including html tags. The question is about the div **containing** a word.

Comment: ZiNNED -its will compares the html tags only if the <div> contains child divs. but the question is mention that " a div contains a certain word ".

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript u can do it lyk this :

```
var teststring = "hi";
var div=document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
if(div.indexOf(testString) > -1 ){
     // your code  goes here 
 }
```

Comment: That's comparing the entire content of the div, including html tags. The question is about the div **containing** a word.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.textContent` in this case.